# Jquery : Select first thee listitem of each unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery. I want to select first three list items(li) of each unordered list (ul) in a single jquery Statement .I am using following code -

```
 <div>
First Unordered List  :
    <ul>
        <li>First Ul li1 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li2 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li3 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li4</li>
        <li>First Ul li5</li>
        <li>First Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
    Second Unordered List
     <ul>
        <li>Second Ul li1 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li2 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li3 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li4</li>
        <li>Second Ul li5</li>
        <li>Second Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here the unordered list could be more then two.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:lt` selector + `find` method.

```
$('ul').find('li:lt(3)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4EgP/

Answer (score 3):

This works fine.

```
 $('ul').find('li:lt(3)');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector and `each` function to loop through your `<ul>` and get the first three `<li>`

```
$("div > ul").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).find('li:lt(3)'));
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDptc/2/) here

Comment: there's no need for a `.each()` loop here, and this doesn't satisfy the OP's request for a single selector that returns all such elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
$("div > ul").find("li:lt(3)").each(function(index, value)
  {
$(this).css('color','Red');
});
```

Comment: `.css()` does an implicit `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a native CSS3 selector that'll obtain the required elements all in one go more efficiently than using `:lt`

```
ul > li:not(:nth-child(n + 4))
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/kS7q5/

Answer (score -1):

Complete code is as below.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var unorder_list = $('div>ul');
    unorder_list.each(function(){
        $(this).find("li:lt(3)").css('color','red');

    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div>
First Unordered List  :
    <ul>
        <li>First Ul li1 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li2 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li3 want to select</li>
        <li>First Ul li4</li>
        <li>First Ul li5</li>
        <li>First Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
    Second Unordered List
     <ul>
        <li>Second Ul li1 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li2 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li3 want to select</li>
        <li>Second Ul li4</li>
        <li>Second Ul li5</li>
        <li>Second Ul li6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```